# C array declarators

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The C standard [link](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) states in Section 6.7.5 Declarators the following syntax:

```
declarator:
   pointeropt direct-declarator

direct-declarator:
   identifier
   ( declarator )
   direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expressionopt ]
   direct-declarator [ static type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expression ]
   direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-list static assignment-expression ]
   direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-listopt * ]
   direct-declarator ( parameter-type-list )
   direct-declarator ( identifier-listopt )
```

We usually write in C something like this when it comes to declare an array: `int my_array[ 10 ]`.

I am trying to match the `10` against the above rules that introduce arrays. The closest I find is `direct-declarator [ type-qualifier-listopt assignment-expressionopt ]` were the `assignment-expression` is not optional.

However, the standard says the following:

```
assignment-expression:
   conditional-expression
   unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
```

I have it very hard to match `10` against the above grammar rule.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you go to the definition of `assignment-expression` and then follow the chain of non-terminals long enough, you'll eventually reach one that matches integer literals.

Comment: This is what I tried to do and failed. What is the chain you are thinking of since ```unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression``` can't be one of them.

Comment: You always pick the one that's just a single non-terminal. So `assignment-expression` -> `conditional-expression` -> `logical-OR-expression` -> `logical-AND-expression` and so on. Eventually you'll reach `primary-expression`.

Comment: yes indead ... a very long chain. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:compiler-construction] for these kind of questions - that tag is for the inner workings of compilers. For theoretical questions regarding the inner workings of the C language, use [tag:c] and [tag:language-lawyer].

Answer (score 4):

Let's see the C grammar:

```
unary-expression:
                 postfix-expression
                 ...

postfix-expression:
               primary-expression
               ...

primary-expression:
               identifier
               constant
               ...

constant:
                 integer-constant
                 ...
```

Comment: yes; that i had in mind; but the rules says: ```unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression```. Which confuses me is the ```assignment-operator assignment-expression``` part.

Comment: @BogdanTanasa It's because result of `?:` is not an l-value and it cannot be assigned.

Comment: @BogdanTanasa, you're looking at the wrong alternative for `assignment-expression`.  The one you're looking at indeed does not match, but the one that is just a *conditional-expression* does.  More generally, at each precedence level **N** lower than that of *primary-expression* (the highest), the expression grammar provides that an expression of level **N+1** is also an expression of level **N**.  That's why, for example, `1 + 1` is acceptable, when `1` is a primary expression and `+` requires the operands to be an *additive-expression* and a *multiplicative-expression*, respectively.